# Fusionchart : Some String Chracters Not Display In Fusion Pie Chart

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, fusioncharts

i'm parsing my MySQL data base data to fusion chart code & draw a pie chart...but unfortunately some characters are not displays..please help to recover this problem... 
here is my code:

```
<?php
include("FusionCharts/FusionCharts.php");
include("special_db_connect.php");
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Exam Result Analysis
</TITLE>
<?php
?>  
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js"></SCRIPT>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
.text{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
-->
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<CENTER>
<?php

// Connect to the DB
$link = connectToDB();
//Generate the chart element
$strXML = "<chart caption='Academic year 2010/2011 results' subCaption='By Grades' pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix=' Students'>";

// Fetch all factory records
$strQuery = "SELECT grade, COUNT(*) 'No_Of_grades' FROM std_results WHERE course_code ='CSC113A' GROUP BY grade";
$result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());

//Iterate through each factory
if ($result) {
while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


//Generate <set label='..' value='..' /> 
$strXML .= "<set label='" . $ors['grade'] . "' value='" . $ors['No_Of_grades'] . "' />";

}
}

//Finally, close <chart> element
$strXML .= "</chart>";

//Create the chart - Pie 3D Chart with data from $strXML
echo renderChart("FusionCharts/Pie3D.swf", "", $strXML, "Results", 600, 300, false, false);
echo "</br></br>";  

mysql_close($link); 

?>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Out put Pie Chart

> [image]

...This is above my code

```
{$strQuery = "SELECT grade, COUNT(*) 'No_Of_grades' FROM std_results WHERE course_code ='CSC113A' GROUP BY grade";}
```

:result of this code in phpmyadmin :

> [image]

Actually this table value will parse to the pie chart..here u can see in grade column A+,C+ values...problem is those string's are not displays in the pie chart.{please visit above pie chart image}.Actually A+ & C+ display without '+' character.{but '-',C-,A- character displays}..It's a problem for me..How can I fix this problem...{Remind Above code is working perfectly..no problem about that only problem is not displaying '+' character .}**

Comment: Out put Pie Chart : http://i.imgur.com/0knwC.jpg

Comment: mysql table : http://i.imgur.com/zGIuX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to encode the sign + with %2B:

```
$strXML .= "<set label='" . str_replace('+', '%2B', $ors['grade']) . "' value='" . $ors['No_Of_grades'] . "' />";
```